# Can't get JS function working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this form with bootstrap but I can't find why it's not working properly ant I've no idea why.

HEAD>>

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/corrections.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/JQuery-2.1.1-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
```

--> code here

```
</body>
```

HTML >>

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <form class="form-inline well">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="text">Some label</label>
                <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text here">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Ok</button>

            <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">
                <h4>Error</h4>
                Required amount of letters is 4
            </div>

            <div class="success alert-success" style="display:none">
                <h4>Success</h4>
                You have the required amount of letters
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
```

JS >>

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $("form").on("submit", function () {
                if ($("input").val().length < 4) {                    
                    $("div.form-group").addClass("has-error");
                    $("div.alert").show("slow").delay(4000).hide("slow");
                    return;    
                } else if ($("input").val().length > 3) {
                    $("div.form-group").addClass("has-success");
                    $("div.success").show("slow").delay(4000).hide("slow");
                    return;   
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

the alert class shows everytime, any idea why?

Comment: `$("input").val().length` is probably always less than 4. I don't see a reason for that to happen given your code, but without further details there isn't much we can do.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't use `$('input')` as that returns all inputs (in this case only one, but you could better use `$('#text')`. 2. Tested the code in JSFiddle.net, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/16hwxbys/

Comment: i dont really understand your answer !! no matter what i type and submit in the input , 2 or 10 letters , it' always the same

Comment: thank you jabbink, solves my problem

Comment: Kevin B>> I hope you don't take it personally, the answer was just not clear for me , thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `$("input")` here is unusual. That selector will pull back all elements on the page that are `<input>`s, which is almost certainly not what you mean. (If there are other `input`s on the page, you might get exactly what you're describing.) Use a more precise selector, like `$("#text")`, and maybe use debug to output the value of `val().length` so you know what you're evaluating.

(On a side note, "text" is not a very useful name for a text input, and your else-if seems redundant, but they probably aren't causing problems in your code.)

Comment: reviewing my previous questions , it seems i ow you a proper thank you, thank you then